# Exising Lending Library Web Service API Specifications and Integration Tools

Tags: web-services, api, amazon-web-services

I want to create web services for my local [public library](http://www.prattlibrary.org/)'s books and media collections. In particular I'd like to create mashups with that data and the [New York Times best-seller lists](http://developer.nytimes.com/), [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/) and [Netflix](http://developer.netflix.com/). For me, the ability to see the most highly rated fantasy books from Amazon and knowing if the library owns a copy is the use case I most often consider.

I'm looking for answers about:

1. **API Specifications**: XML DTDs, REST URL patterns others have used, web service method documentation. Sources might include other libraries that have done something similar, public or private.
2. **Integration Tools**: I assume there are probably a limited number of dominant systems libraries use to manage their collections, as such if there are any tools out there for the purpose of sharing data within them.

The only thing I've found remotely along these lines is [libx](http://libx.org/), but this is a browser plugin for facilitating search for a given library, but does not seem offer anything along the lines of providing for use in other contexts.

Finally, I know I could accomplish all of this by consuming the 3rd party services above and writing a screen scraper for the library's online catalog. But I'm really hoping someone has someone knowledge about existing tools for extracting data from library systems or specs for sharing it that might facilitate this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libx.org also has MAJAX listed as such a link, and a little bit of link-following from there gets you to http://xisbn.worldcat.org/liblook/index.htm

Perhaps some of those could give you a hint?

But really, all of these will depend on your local library doing something - that catalogue search page doesn't seem to support searching by ISBN.